# This resource is no longer available under v1 APIs in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to post on linkedin with the help of api. It returns error saying

`This resource is no longer available under v1 APIs.`
How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linkdin [dropped support](https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates) of V1 API in 2019.

If you're working on legacy code or following V1 tutorials, you may want to read this official [migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/company-pages-migration).